# How to make an HTML element fit to 100% viewport but also scale when being zoomed using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I know that to make an element to fit the viewport width, we can set its width to 100vw

```
body {
    width: 100vw;
}
```

but when we zoom in, the element would stay the same size instead of zooming in because 100vw didnt change as the viewport didnt change.
If I want my element to zoom in I have to set the width with units like em or rem

```
body {
    width: xrem;
}
```

but how could I determine x when the viewport changes on every device.

Is there a way to set the body width to 100vw but also scale when we zoom in.

Comment: The question is just way too confusing. I will recommend making it more clear, adding more information and also maybe the code snippet as well.

Comment: If you don't want to set a realtive width, try setting an absolute width? Like `1000px`?

Comment: No, I want to set a relative width 100vw but if I set like that it wont scale when I zoom in/out. I want the same behavior like this stackoverflow page when opened on a mobile device, its width is the same as the viewport width, and it would scale up with the same ratio when I zoom in the page over 100%, then a scrollbar would appear. But it wont scale down less than 100% if I zoom out the page under 100%.

Comment: Try to add `html, body { height: 100%;}` to solve this.